# Jquery dynamically added forms are not clickable and do not allow any input (all the ui elements can not be focused or clicked)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a container to add elements to it as follow

```
<div>
<div id="mainForm" class="form-container">
</div>
<button class="add-button" value="Add" />
</div>
```

then on button click

```
$(".add-button").click(function () {
    add($(this).parent().find(".form-container:first").prop("id"), getID());
});

function getID(){
var d = new Date();
return d.getYear().toString() + d.getMonth().toString() + d.getDate().toString() + d.getHours().toString() + d.getMinutes().toString() + d.getSeconds().toString() + d.getMilliseconds().toString();
}

function add(id, parentid){
var form = "<div class='form-item' id='" + id + "'>";

form += "<div class='item-data row'>";
form += "<div class='col-lg-5 col-sm-5'>";
form += "<select><option value='1'>Item 1</option></select>";
form += "</div>"
form += "<div class='col-lg-5 col-sm-5'>";
form += "<input type='text'/>";
form += "</div>"
form += "<div class='col-lg-2 col-sm-2'>";
form += "<input type='checkbox' id='ck" + id + "'/><label for='ck" + id + "'>Only</label>";
form += "</div>"
form += "</div>";

form += "<div class='item-sub row'>";
form += "<div class='item-sub-form' id='sf" + id + "'></div>";
form += "<button class='add-button' value='Add'/>";
form += "</div>";

form += "</div>"

$("#" + parentid).append(form);
}
```

when click add button the ui created but i can't select from the dropdown list, the check box also is not clickable and text box does not allow input (all the ui elements can not be focused or clicked).

All UI displayed as image

Comment: Your inputs aren't inside the `<form>`

Comment: You should still be able to click on them. Can you create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I think now its clear please see it again

Comment: You can't have a form inside another form.

Comment: I tried it and it is not about nested forms. The same problem if i used a div instead of form

Comment: I changed the structure of the elements and its worked but i didn't figure the problem out